# Is Gunicorn's gthread async worker analogous to Waitress?

Tags: wsgi, gunicorn, waitress

I've read some posts from 2013 that the Gunicorn team was planning to build a threaded buffering layer worker model, similar to how Waitress works. Is that what the gthread async worker does? The gthread workers were released with version 19.0 in 2014.

Waitress has a master async thread that buffers requests, and enqueues each request to one of its sync worker threads when the request I/O is finished.

Gunicorn gthread doesn't have much documentation, but it sounds similar. From the [docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.0/design.html#asyncio-workers):

> The worker gthread is a threaded worker. It accepts connections in the main loop, accepted connections are are added to the thread pool as a connection job.

I only ask because I am not super knowledgeable about python async I/O code, though a cursory reading of the gthread.py seems to indicate that it is a socket-buffering process that protects worker threads from long-I/O requests (and buffers the response I/O as well).

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py

Comment: I have never used waitress but looking at the Gunicorn code it is a simple wrapper around `concurrent.futures`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Answer (score 1):

The threaded worker in Gunicorn does not buffer I/O and does not read the request body in the main thread.

The main loop asynchronously handles calling `accept()`[[1](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py#L130)], but then the socket is immediately submitted to the thread pool[[2](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py#L124)].

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn doesn't have HTTP request buffering, which is something you can find in Waitress. Waitress also has the advantage that it fully supports Windows.